# how to display multi arc start at custom angle in circle flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, graphics

I'm searching to represent a range of time in 12 hours clock
i tried to represent several colorized arc in once circle that every arc has specified start angle
[image: example]

I already use sync fusion package, it allows to set start angle but only for the main circle not forevery arc

I tried many package as fl chart , pie chart, sync fusion but i didn't get what i searching for

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Have you tried Highcharts? Its extremely popular in JS domain, they have the Flutter plugin as well. https://pub.dev/packages/high_chart

Comment: thank you for the information that i wasn't knew about SyncFysion

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing it and came up with following solution

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:angles/angles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Pie Chart';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: SizedBox.square(
            dimension: 200,
            child: PieChart(
              // data could be list of num
              data: [64, 128, 73, 15, 72],
//              color: Colors.green,
              dividerColor: Colors.white,
              minOpacity: 0.2,
              startAngle: 65,
//              dividerWidth: 5,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PieChart<T extends num> extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? startAngle;
  final int? dividerWidth;
  final Color? dividerColor;
  final Color? color;
  final double? minOpacity;
  final List<T> data;

  const PieChart({
    super.key,
    required this.data,
    this.startAngle,
    this.dividerWidth,
    this.dividerColor,
    this.color,
    this.minOpacity,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final inheritedTheme = Theme.of(context).extension<PieChartTheme>() ??
        PieChartTheme(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        );

    final pieChartTheme = PieChartTheme(
      color: color ?? inheritedTheme.color,
      dividerColor: dividerColor ?? inheritedTheme.dividerColor,
      dividerWidth: dividerWidth ?? inheritedTheme.dividerWidth,
      startAngle: startAngle ?? inheritedTheme.startAngle,
      minOpacity: minOpacity ?? inheritedTheme.minOpacity,
    );

    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _PieChartPainter(
        data: data,
        pieChartTheme: pieChartTheme,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PieChartPainter<T extends num> extends CustomPainter {
  final PieChartTheme pieChartTheme;
  final List<T> data;

  const _PieChartPainter({required this.data, required this.pieChartTheme});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final total = data.fold(0.0, (p, e) => p + e);

    final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    final radius = rect.center.dx;

    double startAngle = Angle.degrees(pieChartTheme.startAngle).radians;
    double sweepAngle = 0;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = pieChartTheme.dividerWidth.toDouble();

    final dividerColor = pieChartTheme.dividerColor;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      startAngle += sweepAngle;
      sweepAngle = data[i] / total * 2 * pi;

      double opacity = 1.0 - i / data.length * (1 - pieChartTheme.minOpacity);
      final color = pieChartTheme.color!.withOpacity(opacity);
      paint
        ..color = color
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

      final path = Path()
        ..moveTo(rect.center.dx, rect.center.dy)
        ..lineTo(radius * cos(startAngle + sweepAngle),
            radius * sin(startAngle + sweepAngle))
        ..addArc(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height), startAngle,
            sweepAngle)
        ..lineTo(rect.center.dx, rect.center.dy)
        ..close();

      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

      if (dividerColor != null) {
        paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        paint.color = dividerColor;
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(rect.center.dx, rect.center.dy);
        Path path = Path()
          ..moveTo(0, 0)
          ..lineTo(radius * cos(startAngle), radius * sin(startAngle))
          ..moveTo(radius * cos(startAngle + sweepAngle),
              radius * sin(startAngle + sweepAngle))
          ..lineTo(0, 0)
          ..close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.restore();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class PieChartTheme extends ThemeExtension<PieChartTheme> {
  final double startAngle;
  final int dividerWidth;
  final Color? dividerColor;
  final Color? color;
  final double minOpacity;

  PieChartTheme(
      {this.startAngle = 0,
      this.dividerWidth = 2,
      this.dividerColor,
      this.color,
      this.minOpacity = 0.5});

  @override
  ThemeExtension<PieChartTheme> lerp(covariant PieChartTheme? other, double t) {
    if (other == null) {
      return this;
    }
    return PieChartTheme(
      startAngle: lerpDouble(startAngle, other.startAngle, t)!,
      color: Color.lerp(color, other.color, t),
      dividerColor: Color.lerp(color, other.color, t),
      dividerWidth:
          (dividerWidth + (other.dividerWidth - dividerWidth) * t).round(),
      minOpacity: lerpDouble(minOpacity, other.minOpacity, t)!,
    );
  }

  @override
  ThemeExtension<PieChartTheme> copyWith({
    double? startAngle,
    int? dividerWidth,
    Color? dividerColor,
    Color? color,
    double? minOpacity,
  }) {
    return PieChartTheme(
      startAngle: startAngle ?? this.startAngle,
      dividerWidth: dividerWidth ?? this.dividerWidth,
      dividerColor: dividerColor ?? this.dividerColor,
      color: color ?? this.color,
      minOpacity: minOpacity ?? this.minOpacity,
    );
  }
}
```

`angles` package is dependency.

Sample output
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't quite address my query. Specifically, I'm looking to create a complete circle and then be able to add a colorized slice (one or multi slice)  by entering values for the start and end angles. For instance, if I input a start angle of 30 degrees and an end angle of 60 degrees, it should display that slice within the circle.

Comment: Ok. Above solution can be modified for the same behaviour. Do you still want the solution or have you found one?